# LoadRunner 11.52 records empty actions with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, loadrunner

I am trying to record with Chrome in LoadRunner for the first time (having to record a mobile app through an emulator that only works in Chrome), but when recording with Web (HTTP/HTML) protocol in Chrome I only get empty actions, no events are recorded (tried with several "standard" web pages).

LoadRunner opens Chrome fine, I click a few links and then stop recording, but script actions remain empty. Using HTML-style recoring.

**Setup:**
Windows 7 64 bit SP1
Loadrunner VuGen v11.52
Chrome v27.0

I have colleagues that manage to record fine with similar (if not exact same) setup. Has anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must close all Chrome windows before starting recording and use only the window that VuGen opens to record. Also make sure no chrome processes running before recording.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple. I thought I had tried that, but obviously not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not record the actual device with vugen instead of an emulator?

Keep in mind you are trying to use a 32 bit application to record a 64 bit application.   I would even go so far as to recommend that you look at using the proxy model recording as an HTTP proxy for the "old recording engine."

Comment: Hmm yeah I'll have a closer look on those options, thanks :-)